# how to connect my java base desktop application with Quickbooks to fetch data?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am new for the QuickBooks. Can any one guide me what steps I required to load data from Buickbook in my local application and Do i required to make Webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FAQs
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0058_FAQ

This seems like a duplicate question as well.

thanks
Jarred